# calling salesforce rest api from java to create leads

Tags: rest-api, leads, java

I am writting below code to create leads in salesforce crm through its rest full api.But it is giving error 401.Can any one help me to sort out this issue.

```
static String  generateHeader() {
        oauthHeader = new BasicHeader("Authorization",AuthorizationTokenProvider.provideToken()) ;
        baseUri = AuthProps.RESOURCECREATEURL + AuthProps.REST_ENDPOINT + AuthProps.API_VERSION ;
        System.out.println("baseUri: "+ baseUri); 
        return baseUri;

    }
 public static void createLeads() {
     System.out.println("\n_______________ Lead INSERT _______________");
     String uri = generateHeader() + "/sobjects/lead/";
     System.out.println("uri" +uri);
     try {
         //create the JSON object containing the new lead details.
         JSONObject leads = new JSONObject();
         leads.put("RecordTypeId","0126A000000BAIzQAO");
         leads.put("FirstName", "Prabhat");
         leads.put("Company", "Tests Enterprises");
         leads.put("LeadProfile__c", "");
         leads.put("Email", "test@email.com");
         leads.put("Phone", "1155550000");
         leads.put("MobilePhone", "11955550000");
         leads.put("ContactPreference__c", "Email");
         leads.put("CNPJ__c", "10212469000148");
         leads.put("CPF__c", "");
         leads.put("Street", "");
         leads.put("PostalCode", "");
         leads.put("City", "");
         leads.put("State", "");
         leads.put("Country", "");
         leads.put("DealerCode__c", "04659");
         leads.put("TMA__c", "KHC");
         leads.put("Catalog__c", "KAA8");
         leads.put("ModelYear__c", "2018");
         leads.put("Color__c", "");
         leads.put("InternalFinish__c", "");
         leads.put("LeadSource", "Web");
         leads.put("LeadSubSource__c", "Website");
         leads.put("InterestType__c", "");
         leads.put("AgreeReceiveContact__c", "true");
         System.out.println("JSON for order record to be inserted:\n" + leads.toString(1));
         //Construct the objects needed for the request
         HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
         HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(uri);
         httpPost.addHeader(oauthHeader);
        // httpPost.addHeader(prettyPrintHeader);
         // The message we are going to post
         StringEntity body = new StringEntity(leads.toString(1));
         System.out.println("the body is "+body.toString());
         body.setContentType("application/json");
         httpPost.setEntity(body);
         System.out.println("the post request is"+httpPost.toString());
         //Make the request
         HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
         //Process the results
         int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
         if (statusCode == 201) {
             String response_string = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
             JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response_string);
             // Store the retrieved lead id to use when we update the lead.
           String leadsId = json.getString("id");
             System.out.println("New order id from response: " + leadsId);
         } else {
             System.out.println("Insertion unsuccessful. Status code returned is " + statusCode);
         }
     } catch (JSONException e) {
         System.out.println("Issue creating JSON or processing results");
         e.printStackTrace();
     } catch (IOException ioe) {
         ioe.printStackTrace();
     } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
         npe.printStackTrace();
     }
 } 

 public static void main(String agrs[]) {
     createLeads();
 }
```

}

Thanks.

Comment: [Error code 401](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/errorcodes.htm) means `The session ID or OAuth token used has expired or is invalid. The response body contains the message and errorCode.` Check your authentication details if its valid.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am using the same data on postman and it is working. the . only thing that i am getting on postman is when in header Authorization :Bereer<space> access_code then it is working but not giving the space than it showing session expiered.

Comment: A space is required `Authorization: Bearer access_token`, Check ['Step Two: Set Up Authorization'](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/quickstart_oauth.htm)

Comment: Thanks Raul , I am writing  this code and even getting error  code 400. static String getAuthValue(String token) {
  String bearer = AuthProps.BEARER;
  String whitespace=" ";
  StringBuilder str=new StringBuilder();
  str.append(bearer);
  str.append(whitespace);
  str.append(token);
  return str.toString();

 }

Comment: Could you try debugging the string that is being returned by the method `AuthorizationTokenProvider.provideToken()` ? The bearer in the authorization header has to be `Bearer <token>` with bearer having the same case for all the letters as mentioned.

Comment: Thanks Mohit, I am getting Authorisation value as  Bearer 00Dm00000004zIE!AQUAQIyKgESyFkOYXOadQjxfozOLbrY2d.ggb79F74aQlopqslSsv_hVtgAEMHl7WQwUBQyHjRtHJHHq****(star is for the purpose of hiding credential)

Comment: Thanks @Raul and Mohit. It's working now. the issue was with my request body. That I have corrected and it is working fine now. Thanks a lot for your quick help.